# Fail to make Anyobject to NSString in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

There's an exception when I run it.

```
self.year = value as! NSString
```

Exception:

```
 Could not cast value of type '__NSDate' (0x1051bd6a0) to 'NSString' (0x10564d8e0).
```

What am I missing ?

```
var  datePicker = ActionSheetDatePicker(title: "Date:",datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode.Date, selectedDate: NSDate(),doneBlock: { 

   picker, value, index in

   self.year = value as! NSString 

   println("year = \(year)")
   println("value = \(value)")

   return
   }, cancelBlock: { ActionStringCancelBlock in return }, origin: sender.superview!.superview)
```

Comment: Show us the exception too

Comment: Your value is of NSDate type.But you are type casting to NSString by force.

Comment: NSDate can't be casted to string. You need an NSDateFormatter for that.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to convert date to string via your selected value

```
let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
let dateStr: String = formatter.string(from: value as! Date)
```

You can use any other format like : "yyyy" or "HH:mm:ss" etc.

and set it to your year variable

```
self.year = dateStr
```